# Building ( Cmake ) QtGStreamer on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, build, cmake, gstreamer, qtgstreamer

I have a problem with Qt binding for Gstreamer. Im using procedure from README from QtGStreamer package but I get some error while executing cmake command.

Basic info:

```
    Mac OS X v. 10.6.8
    GStreamer v. 0.10.36 + dependencies (installed through MacPorts) 
    Cmake v. 2.8.10 + dependencies  (installed through MacPorts)
    Boost v. 1.52.0 + dependencies  (installed through MacPorts)
    Qt v 4.8 (installed through SDK installer)
```

Sugested build procedure:

```
    $ mkdir build && cd build
    $ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/installation/prefix
    $ make
    $ make install
```

Result of cmake:

```
    $ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp1/install
    -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.2.1
    -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.2.1
    -- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
    -- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
    -- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
    -- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
    -- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
    -- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
    -- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Looking for Q_WS_X11
    -- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found
    -- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
    -- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found
    -- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
    -- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
    -- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
    -- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - found
    -- Looking for QT_MAC_USE_COCOA
    -- Looking for QT_MAC_USE_COCOA - found
    -- Found Qt4: /opt/local/bin/qmake (found version "4.8.4") 
    -- Boost version: 1.52.0
    -- Found PkgConfig: /opt/local/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.27.1") 
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-0.10'
    --   found gstreamer-0.10, version 0.10.36
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
    --   found gstreamer-base-0.10, version 0.10.36
    -- Found GSTREAMER_BASE_LIBRARY: /opt/local/lib/libgstbase-0.10.dylib
    -- Found GSTREAMER_BASE_INCLUDE_DIR: /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers/gst/base
    -- Found GStreamer: /opt/local/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.dylib (Required is at least version "0.10.33") 
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10'
    --   package 'gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10' not found
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
    --   package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' not found
    -- Could NOT find GSTREAMER_APP_LIBRARY
    -- Found GSTREAMER_APP_INCLUDE_DIR: /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers/gst/app
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-interfaces-0.10'
    --   package 'gstreamer-interfaces-0.10' not found
    -- Could NOT find GSTREAMER_INTERFACES_LIBRARY
    -- Found GSTREAMER_INTERFACES_INCLUDE_DIR: /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers/gst/interfaces
    -- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
    --   package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' not found
    -- Could NOT find GSTREAMER_VIDEO_LIBRARY
    -- Found GSTREAMER_VIDEO_INCLUDE_DIR: /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers/gst/video
    -- Could NOT find GStreamerPluginsBase (missing:  GSTREAMER_APP_LIBRARY GSTREAMER_INTERFACES_LIBRARY GSTREAMER_VIDEO_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "0.10.33")
    -- checking for module 'glib-2.0'
    --   found glib-2.0, version 2.34.3
    -- Found GLIB2: /opt/local/lib/libglib-2.0.dylib  
    -- checking for module 'gobject-2.0'
    --   found gobject-2.0, version 2.34.3
    -- Found GObject: /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers/gobject  
    -- Found OpenGL: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework  
    -- Could NOT find OpenGLES2 (missing:  OPENGLES2_INCLUDE_DIR OPENGLES2_LIBRARY) 
    -- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- The following external packages were located on your system.
    -- This installation will have the extra features provided by these packages.
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------    * Qt 4 - Required for building everything    * QtOpenGL - Required for OpenGL acceleration in qtvideosink and QtGStreamerUi    * QtDeclarative - Required for building QML support    * Boost - Required for building QtGLib    * GStreamer - Required to build QtGStreamer    * GStreamer base library - Used for building the qwidgetvideosink element    * GLib - Required to build QtGLib    * GObject - Required to build QtGLib    * OpenGL - Required for OpenGL rendering support in qtvideosink (desktop only)

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- The following OPTIONAL packages could NOT be located on your system.
    -- Consider installing them to enable more features from this software.
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------    * GStreamer video library (0.10.33 or higher)  
         Used for building the qwidgetvideosink element    * OpenGLES (2.0 or higher)  
         Required for OpenGLES rendering support in qtvideosink (embedded only)    * Doxygen  
         Used to generate the API documentation

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- The following REQUIRED packages could NOT be located on your system.
    -- You must install these packages before continuing.
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------    * GStreamer app library (0.10.33 or higher)  
         Required to build QtGStreamerUtils    * GStreamer interfaces library (0.10.33 or higher)  
         Required to build QtGStreamer

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    CMake Error at cmake/modules/MacroLogFeature.cmake:141 (MESSAGE):   Exiting: Missing Requirements Call Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:152 (macro_display_feature_log)


    CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files: GSTREAMER_APP_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
        linked by target "QtGStreamerUtils" in directory /Users/madman/Downloads/RELEASE-0.10.2/src/QGst GSTREAMER_INTERFACES_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
        linked by target "QtGStreamer" in directory /Users/madman/Downloads/RELEASE-0.10.2/src/QGst

    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I need this binding to develop an app for playing MJPEG/ASF streams from CCTV cameras. I have tried libvlc already but there is no easy way to capture streams while they are already displayed... GStreamer is the only alternative because it's gonna be cross platform application

I'm fairly new to C++/Qt programming and whole build/compile magic is still little bit confusing for me...

I know there is no simple answer how to build QtGstreamer binding but I'm gonna be very grateful for any help

Comment: I am dealing with a similar issue. The problem is that the cmake system is using Find<name of library>.cmake files that aren't working and I think it's because those cmake scripts try to use pkg-config but pkg-config isn't working because it's too old. I'm on OSX too, so it might be an OSX thing...